# How to link to specific line number on AWS CodeCommit

Tags: aws-codecommit

I know you can link to a specific line number on GitHub using the syntax `#L55` where 55 is the line number. How do you link to a specific line number in AWS CodeCommit? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AWS CodeCommit doesn't support linking to line numbers at this time.